# How to select cells and subtract the numbers in the cells only when they match certain conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I'm creating an inventory management spreadsheet for my food business and I'm stuck with how to use IF, MATCH, or whatever formulas are appropriate to do this.

Specific scenario:
If a cell in the range of B23:B67 contains "Non-sales", then I want to subtract the numbers in cells in the range of D23:D67 corresponding to "Non-sales" in the column B from D68 and multiply by D22.

Current formula:

```
=IF($B23="Non-sales",(D68-D23)*D22)
```

Problem:
Right now, I'm only selecting the row 23, but I want to select the range of B23:B67 for B23, and the range of D23:D67 for D23 in this formula.

Comment: You need to work with absolute cell reference and the Array formula (CSE),,, but what would be better,, plz [edit] your post & share some sample data or the WB on cloud, help us to test the method!!

Comment: Your question is not very clearly, are D68 and D22 fixed in formula? What the result do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a SUMIF here, unless I misunderstood your question. It sounds like the core of this hinges on getting the SUM of all the cells in D23:D67 which correspond to cells in B23:B67 which say "non-sales". To do that, use this:

```
=SUMIF($B$23:$B$67,"Non-sales",$D$23:$D$67)
```

Now you can subtract that total from D68 then multiply by D22. If on the other hand you want to sum the values found when you subtract each of the required D23:D67 values from D68 (rather than subtracting the total from just one of D68), you could use:

```
=($D$68*countif($B$23:$B$67,"Non-sales"))-SUMIF($B$23:$B$67,"Non-sales",$D$23:$D$67)
```